# How do I find the process generating a lot of network traffic?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

My machine is generating a lot of network traffic, all from the same source port, with many different destinations (found this out by running `iftop -P`, and from my router's logs).

How do I find the process that is generating this traffic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i would use:

```
netstat -punta | grep <src port>
```

it will give you PIDs and binary name for each

Comment: What's the point of specifying -t and -u if -a is given?

Comment: @tink so you dont get UNIX domain sockets and so you get UDP and TCP in connected or listen states

Comment: I find -atup and -atunp faster to type :)

Comment: @XTL -punta is easier for me to remember because its very close to a naughty word in spanish :D

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this (for port 80):

```
netstat -p --numeric-ports | grep :80
```

This is not the best solution, but should give the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck using [nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) which has an active github repo

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

or compile from source

```
git clone https://github.com/raboof/nethogs.git
cd nethogs
make
sudo make install
```

... then view traffic, say on your WiFi interface :

```
sudo nethogs wlan0
```